# Performance question - Lambda based API - hosted directly on AWS vs. through Netlify Functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, redis, aws-lambda, netlify

Hey guys so I'm developing a corona api for a hackathon and we currently have a "classic" setup running on an EC2 VM with the data simply in .json files on disk.

For the default route, `/daily`, it takes approximately 400-600ms.

Now I've been messing around with redesigning it with serverless functions which definitely works, however performance-wise I'm severely underwhelmed.

I did it once in AWS directly, with their API Gateway and Lambda functions with the data in DynamoDB and a redis cache (redis cloud).

So when the request comes in, it first checks redis, and if the key can't be found, it queries dynamo and returns the result.

This works great, with response times (after the first one where the lambda has a cold-start / the redis entry may not exist) a bit lower around 200-400ms.

Howeverrr, setting up these individual Lambda functions with all the IAM configuration required with AWS was a pain in the butt.

So as I'm a big fan of Netlify as well, I decided to try it through their functions ( I know they're basically just lambdas as well ). Anyway, I have it using the same redis cache and instead of dynamo (because I couldn't figure out the IAM to let netlify read our dynamodb) I used faunadb as the db which works well enough. The problem is, even when the redis entry exists, the requests through netlify functions take AT LEAST 1s, often around 1.3s-1.5s

Any idea why the large discrepancy?

The AWS Lambda version is hosted in eu-central-1 and so is the redis cloud instance. I'm not sure where netlify setup our functions. Thats the only way I can explain the difference, when both are simply hitting the redis cache and returning the result. Maybe the netlify function is in us-east-1 or somewhere further away where the check to redis / get from redis takes much longer.

**EDIT 1**:
Screenshot from monitoring software:
[image: screenshot]

**EDIT 2**: 
So I tested a netlify function route where it just returns on object of some random content, without making any other requests, and it was just as fast as the AWS one. So it seems my hypothesis about the request from netlify's aws region, wherever they put my function, is taking that much longer to query redis than the lambda version where I could tell it specifically which region to execute from..

Any other ideas / tips?

Comment: i thought netlify just use aws lambda under the hood? the performance is probably same. netlify seesm to have better developer experience though.

Comment: Netlify does just use aws lambda under the hood - thats why I was so confused about the performance discrepancy. And netlify has a 1000x better develoepr experience, thats why I want to use them instead of aws lambda directly haha.